# Get wordpress footer with specific css rule apllied

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In my custom Wordpress template, I want to load with specific `css` class applied to specific class.

I load footer in my `templates` by `<?php get_footer(); ?>` function. But I want to load footer with **.nopadding** class `.nopadding{padding: 0px !important}` in the `<div class"main-footer">` as `<div class="main-footer no-padding">` but I want to apply the rule from the page template only, as the style is only `template-specific` rule.

My footer hierarchy -

```
<footer id="footer" class="footer-h">
<div class="main-footer>
<div class="container row">
<div class="f-copyright">
</div>
<div>
</div>
</footer>
```

I want a `PHP` function to add the `no-padding` class to `<div class="main-footer>` from the page template, as this is page-template specific rule.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you tried so far in order to achieve this. It seems by the way you express your problem that you just want to solve this issue when actually SO is a platform to share code and ask for insights based on previous work.

Comment: I have `page` templates, in one specific page `template` `page-nopadding.php` I want to load footer with` padding:0px;`. My default theme css file has padding in left and right, but for specific page, there will be `no-padding` class applied to a `footer div element`

Comment: It is much preferable to do this on the server side, either in CSS or using the built-in WP functions in PHP. Adding classes using JS on the front end should only be used when an interaction on the front end triggers a change in the styling. Either of the 2 unaccepted answers are better solutions than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has a build in function specifically for this purpose and it is

```
is_page_template()
```

So you can try something like this in your footer.

```
<footer id="footer" class="footer-h">
    <div class="main-footer <?php if(is_page_template('template.php')){ echo 'no-padding'; } ?>">
        <div class="container row">
            <div class="f-copyright">
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

In the above code just replace the `template.php` with the file name of your template, and if the template is sitting in a sub directory of the theme then just add the correct path like `'templates/template.php'` where templates is the name of sub directory.

You can learn more about this function from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)
Hope it helps.

Comment: In your case with name of template `page-nopadding.php` you can use 
<div class="main-footer <?php if(is_page_template('page-nopadding.php')){ echo 'no-padding'; } ?>">

Comment: This does not work - footer div is unchanged. PHP doesn't run from footer or any issues, but doesn't work

Comment: are you setting the path of template file correct in the function ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution for this if you want to avoid conditional checks is to simply add css rules that depend on the `<body>` tag having a matching class to the template.

On the page with the template in question, go to developer tools, look at the source code and find the class that will look something like this:

```
<body class="page-template page-template-page-nopadding ...">
```

Get whatever that second class name is and then you can add targeted CSS to your style.css like so:

```
body.page-template-page-nopadding footer.footer-h{
    /* write your css rules here */
    padding:0;
}
body.page-template-page-nopadding .f-copyright{
    font-size:0.8rem;
    padding:0;
    /* add more as needed */
}
```

This is the easiest way to address page specific styling - you can literally comb through the entire template and just apply different styles to every element and every area without writing a single conditional statement in PHP.

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest solution offered so far, and is much preferable to the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks FluffyKitten.  I generally save using php conditions for when I need different output or different HTML structure.  I just figure that since the identifying class is already in place for this purpose, you’d just want to leverage what’s already there. 